# How to skip Conflict files in 'git am'

Tags: git, github

I want to skip the conflict files during 'git am', Other files (without conflict) should merge with patch.

I am using below command:

```
git am -3 <patch>
```

Pls suggest.

Comment: [`git am`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-am) is not "auto merge" but "apply mailbox".